# Do not log warnings for a single function

Tags: python, logging

Say I have a dict of people and their ages.

```py
ages = {"Tom": 44, "Amy": 15, "Dude": 23, "Namey McNameface": 71}
```

I then want to check if someone can drive a car. If they're legally not allowed to do so, a warning should be raised.

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def can_drive_car(name):
    if ages[name] < 16:
        logger.warning("{} shouldn't be doing that".format(name))
        return False
    return True

if can_drive_car("Dude"): force_to_drive_me_home("Dude")
```

I'd like to have a function that gets the names of *everyone* legally allowed to drive a car. Because the requirements are *extremely complex*, it will be easiest for the checking function to call the function that just checks one person and return all the people for whom that function returned True.

```py
def get_everyone_who_can_drive():
    return [p for p in ages.keys() if can_drive_car(p)]

>>> get_everyone_who_can_drive()
["Tom", "Dude", "Namey McNameface"]
```

Great! Now I have a list of everyone who can drive me home without going to jail.

Problem: I called a function that raised a warning when it evaluated Amy. The thing is, I wasn't checking Amy specifically, so even though I want that warning to appear when I evaluate people individually, I don't want it to appear when I'm evaluating everyone at the same time.

By changing only `get_everyone_who_can_drive`, without passing an argument, and without restructuring the programme to be even slightly sane, how can I prevent the warning from appearing?

Comment: I'd separate `can_drive_car` into a function that returns a list of problems and another function that logs them and returns `True` if `reasons_why_cant_drive_car()` is empty and `False` otherwise, but I'd call it "restructuring the programme to be even slightly sane". The only way to do this in an insane way would be to turn off the logger in `get_everyone_who_can_drive` and turn it back on again.

Answer (score 0):

Move the logging from the function `can_drive_car` to the code that calls the function

```
def can_drive_car(name):
    return ages[name] >= 16

if can_drive_car("Dude"):
    force_to_drive_me_home("Dude")
else:
    logger.warning("Dude shouldn't be doing that")
```

Now your comprehension will not log warnings

EDIT:

If you can access the logger that is producing the warnings then you can set the log level to something higher like ERROR so that the warning will not be logged

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(<name of module>)
previous_level = logger.level
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
get_everyone_who_can_drive()
logger.setLevel(previous_level)
```

Comment: For my current use case, the warning cannot leave `can_drive_car` without major restructuring.

Comment: Do you have access to change the logger?

Comment: I'm uncertain. This is for a package - the user should be able to call `get_everyone_who_can_drive` and not be concerned about any warnings that pop up. I'm not sure what I can and can't do with regards to logging without disrupting the user experience.

Comment: Editing my answer, if you can access the logger you can potentially change the log level so that warnings are not logged